# Identity Server 4, message.State is null or empty

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, openid-connect, identityserver4

I keep receiving an error trying to authenticate using IdentityServer4.  I've looked at a few resources for this issue but all of them do not relate to my issue.
I'm making a json request to `https://localhost:44377/signin-oidc` but this is what is logged from the AspCore Authentication DLL

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMiddleware:Information: Error from RemoteAuthentication: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty..

My Startup.cs configuration looks like this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddTestUsers(Config.GetTestUsers())
    .AddTemporarySigningCredential();



app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { AuthenticationScheme = "cookie" });
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ClientId = "openIdConnectClient",
    Authority = "https://localhost:44377/",
    SignInScheme = "cookie",
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("clientpassword"))
    },
    CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc"
});
```

And the Client I'm trying to Access looks like this

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "openIdConnectClient",
    ClientName = "Example Implicit Client Application",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        "role",
        "customAPI"
    },
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {
        new Secret("superSecretPassword".Sha256())},
    RedirectUris = new List<string> {"https://localhost:44377/signin-oidc"},
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {"https://localhost:44377"}
}
```

Comment: They have a tonne of examples in the idserver repo. Have you looked there?

Comment: I've looked at them I've also been following along with tutorials. I just want authentication working with a test user,  I don't want to migrate their database.

Comment: have you got the middleware ordering correct? This is very specific and has to be correct

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'll check that out

Comment: it's those `app.` that you want to pay special attention to

Comment: It's so frustrating I just want authentication working with a simple solution but it seems like everything has an excess of configuration. I have a bounty open for authentication right now and when I get it working I'll post 3 different ways to authenticate so no one will ever have to go through this pain

Comment: I don't know - I never found it difficult to get a simple auth working... if you want super simplicity don't use id server 4... use bearer tokens

Comment: I was a simple solution but for this I want to be able to support logging in through gmail

Comment: You can do that solely using aspnet core

Comment: You're manually making a JSON request to /signin-oidc? This endpoint is for the interactive browser flow, you should be redirected through it automatically, not making your own request to it. The initial challenge stores its state in the message and needs that back to complete the login. Are you sure you shouldn't be using JwtBearer instead?

Comment: @Tratcher how do I make a sign-in from web-api with no client Im just trying to test from postman

Comment: How can I use JwtBearer instead

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put `AuthenticationScheme = "oidc"` under `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "oidc"
    ClientId = "openIdConnectClient",
    Authority = "https://localhost:44377/",
    SignInScheme = "cookie",
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("clientpassword"))
    },
    CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc"
});
```